# using nginx reverse proxy for docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I am using nginx on my ubuntu machine and setup 2 laravel application using docker and one wordpress website without docker

- Application 1: localhost:8088
- Application 2: localhost:8089

I wanted to achieve is that when someone open localhost so it opens wordpress website and if someone open localhost/app1 it opens application 1 and so on.

So I have created reverse proxy so that it can open my docker container application
This is what I have done

1. sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/website
2. ln -s  /etc/nginx/sites-available/website /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
3. nginx -t
4. systemctl restart nginx

After doing so when I try to open localhost/app1 it shows 404 but it recognise its a laravel app but shows 404

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/website file code

```
server{

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;

    location /app1/{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file named `redirects.map` inside the nginx folder of your application and add a mapping like

```
~^localhost/app1/(.*) localhost:8089/$1;
```

Comment: Please try this approach also - open `/etc/hosts` file and add an entry like 
------------
`127.0.1.1:8089       localhost/app1`

Answer (score 0):

You should change nginx configure from

```
server{

   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;
   root /var/www/html/wordpress;

   location /app1/{
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;
   }

}
```

To

```
server{

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;
    }

}
```